# What's the proper way of terminating a Lua script / thread in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, lua

I am using [`mlua`](https://crates.io/crates/mlua) and Rust to build a scripting engine and a script will only be run one at a time. I was thinking the best approach would be to spawn a thread to run each script. The thread will not be returning any data and could run for infinite time until a user stops it.

My issue is how would I go about stopping a thread mid execution?

For example my Lua script is infinite:

```lua
while true do
    log("I'm stuck in an infinite loop!")
end
```

My current Rust code looks like the following:

```rust
pub struct Script {
    name: String,
    path: PathBuf,
    lua: Arc<Mutex<Lua>>,
    thread: ThreadManager,
    should_stop: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Script {
    pub fn new(name: &str, path: PathBuf) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            path,
            lua: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Lua::new())),
            thread: ThreadManager::new(),
            should_stop: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
        })
    }

    pub fn load(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        let lua = self.lua.lock().unwrap();
        let globals = lua.globals();

        // register API functions here
        globals.set(
            "log",
            lua.create_function(|_, msg: String| {
                info!("{}", msg);
                Ok(())
            })?,
        )?;

        info!("Loaded script: {}", self.name);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        let script_content = std::fs::read_to_string(&self.path);
        let script_content = match script_content {
            Ok(content) => content,
            Err(_) => {
                return Err(Error::RuntimeError(
                    "failed to read script file".to_string(),
                ));
            }
        };
        let lua_arc_clone = Arc::clone(&self.lua);
        let thread_state = self.thread.get_state(&self.name);
        if thread_state == ThreadState::Stopped {
            let is_started = self.thread.start(&self.name, move || {
                let lua = lua_arc_clone.lock().unwrap();
                lua.load(&script_content).exec().unwrap();
            });
            if !is_started {
                warn!("failed to start thread for: {}", self.name);
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        let thread_state = self.thread.get_state(&self.name);
        if thread_state == ThreadState::Running {
            self.thread.stop(&self.name);
            info!("script stopped: {}", self.name);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

To start the thread:

```rust
pub fn start<T>(&mut self, name: &str, t: T) -> bool
where
    T: Fn() + Send + 'static,
{
    let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ThreadState::Running));
    let state_clone = Arc::clone(&state);

    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match *state_clone.lock().unwrap() {
            ThreadState::Running => {
                info!("Running thread");
                t();
            }
            ThreadState::Paused => {
                info!("Paused thread");
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
            }
            ThreadState::Stopped => {
                info!("Stopped thread");
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    self.threads.insert(name.clone().to_string(), state);

    true
}
```

I've tried using signals but the problem is the Lua execution blocking the check ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call [`Thread::reset`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/struct.Thread.html#method.reset) to kill it.

Alternatively, if you switch to async you can `drop` the `AsyncThread` for a similar effect.

An other option is to use `debug.sethook` to force the lua VM to interrupt and yield handing control back to the rust code, however I would assume that will slow down the Lua code as it will keep interrupting itself and waiting for the Rust program to resume it.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to use Thread::reset? I don't see anything listed in the docs or in their examples.

Comment: I've never used it so not really but it looks to me like you give it a new function, and it replaces the existing execution by the new one. You can probably give it an empty function to just abort and terminate.